# What kind of domain logic is *not* appropriate in a CanCan Ability class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Apologies for the rather discursive question but I can't think of a better way to put it. I have an Ability class in my Rails app with some fairly complex logic and am becoming concerned that I am letting CanCan take on too much responsibility. This has led me to wonder what would be a reasonable rule of thumb for when domain logic should or shouldn't go in the Ability class.

An example: Imagine a simplified social network where users can befriend each other. Given users Alice and Bob, Alice may befriend Bob if the following conditions are met:

1. Alice is not suspended.
2. Bob has sent Alice a friend request.
3. Alice and Bob are not already friends.

1 seems an obvious good fit for CanCan. If a user is suspended they cannot befriend people. You could even specify this by giving the user a "suspended" role.

2 seems a pretty good fit - one user granting a permission to another. However is this not rather critical domain logic to be hiving off into an Ability class? Should the Ability call a `can_befriend?` method on the user model to determine this?

3 seems problematic to me. Stopping people befriending people they are already friends with seems not so much a question of permissions, more a question of interface logic. We want to hide the "Befriend" button not because Alice is not permitted to befriend Bob, but because it won't do anything. So if Alice & Bob are already friends, should a call for Alice to `can?(:befriend, bob)` return true or false? And if this logic does belong in the Ability class, what *doesn't* belong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't place any of that to the Ability (even #1). This kind of logic belongs to `User#befriend(user)` (or whatever you'll call it). I use abilities to define actual permissions: users should not be able to post photos to albums which they don't own, etc.

Comment: Right, my problem here really hinges on the fact that I'm not 100% confident in my understanding of the word "permission". Isn't "suspended users cannot befriend anybody" a permission specification?

Comment: To me it's more of a business logic. If I were you, I'd do `<%= show_befriend_button if @user.can_befriend?(another_user)` instead of `... if can? :befriend, another_user`. I don't see real added value in pushing this kind of logic to ability. But cost is obvious.

Comment: Part of CanCan usefulness is that it can build queries for you: `Project.accessible_by(current_ability)`. This doesn't work with complex logic as in your question. So, I guess, my rule of thumb is: if you can't express rules with [Hash of Conditions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities), don't put them in Ability.